# An impossible A to Z journey

Tags: knowledge, geography, cryptic-clues, cryptic-crosswords, azed

**An impossible A to Z journey**

I was chatting with my uncle Van Wetherall and his wife Wanda when VW burst out with

"You know, we did the whole VW thing. We followed the A-Z map in the VW and rolled from Australia to Zanzibar." Wanda chided "Don't be so romantic Van. We never did that, or any A-Z. Anyway they are both islands!" Van retorted "But we did the rest – here's a complete list of where we went".

I scanned the list. "But how did you manage that? Some of those borders are closed."

"With a pile of Nirvana T-shirts and a stack of Rolling Stones LPs we could go anywhere!" he bragged.

I asked "LPs? For heaven's sake!" Van replied "Yes, this was around 1991-2."

I passed the list to Wanda, who said "Oh Van, you are such a dreamer, this is still stretching the truth. We can't have started and finished where you say" and to me "do you think you can make this list into an A-Z crossword?"

- Where did VW imagine they started and finished?
- Why would that have been impossible in the VW?

[image]

**A**bsent any spa in a Black Sea resort (7)
**B**anitsa is enjoyed where I lug Arab around (8)
**C**artoon's "Wot, no clue?" (4)
**D**rank with me to get addled (7)
**E**xported needles to Paris, London and New York (5)
**F**eed me with cheese and wine please! (6)
**G**ot by men in black? Just one in a shade of grey (7)
**H**ome of goulash originally (7)
**I** am seen in Madeira quite a bit (4)
**I**s a serial killer hiding here? (6)
**J**ust Katie enjoying being in the sun (6)
**K**indred one of five, lacking much vowel (10)
**L**ike one of three, in a Baltic sandwich (6)
**M**ight be the source of the river Alph (8)
**N**ice work by Slartibartfast (6)
**O**nce a part of the Ottoman Empire (4)
**P**iquant eclectic dishes served up in an old pan (6)
**Q**uietly reading up a Desiderata quote (5)
**R**esonating with someone in a hurry (6)
**S**tarting in arid Asia, Abu set forth (11)
**S**udden uplifting by an Indiana dust devil (5)
**T**hanksgiving's reprieval (6)
**U**sually like Britain, with bad weather to the east (7)
**V**eiled activity can be found in Rome (11)
**W**here the Earth answers a disputed situation (13)
**X**i likes a gin jinx cocktail kept separate (8)
**Y**ou see visual yoga after its break-up (10)
**Z**apped now I raze it to the ground (5)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The filled in A-Z crossword:

> [image: Filled in crossword]

The clues in detail:

> **A**bsent any spa in a Black Sea resort (7)
>  **ALBANIA** — sp(A IN A BLA)ck
>
>  **B**anitsa is enjoyed where I lug Arab around (8)
>  **BULGARIA** — (I LUG ARAB)*
>
>  **C**artoon's "Wot, no clue?" (4)
>  **CHAD** — British wartime graffito
>
>  **D**rank with me to get addled (7)
>  **DENMARK** — (DRANK ME)*
>
>  **E**xported needles to Paris, London and New York (5)
>  **EGYPT** — exported obelisks ("needles")
>
>  **F**eed me with cheese and wine please! (6)
>  **FRANCE** — known for wine and cheese
>
>  **G**ot by men in black? Just one in a shade of grey (7)
>  **GERMANY** — MAN in GREY*
>
>  **H**ome of goulash originally (7)
>  **HUNGARY** — where goulash comes from
>
>  **I** am seen in Madeira quite a bit (4)
>  **IRAQ** — Made(IRA Q)uite
>
>  **I**s a serial killer hiding here? (6)
>  **ISRAEL** — SERIAL*
>
>  **J**ust Katie enjoying being in the sun (6)
>  **JORDAN** — Katie Price's *nom die guerre* when posing for The Sun's Page 3
>
>  **K**indred one of five, lacking much vowel (10)
>  **KYRGYZSTAN** — Don't be harsh – surely the Y's are vowels here
>
>  **L**ike one of three, in a Baltic sandwich (6)
>  **LATVIA** — sandwiched between fellow Baltic states Lithuania and Estonia
>
>  **M**ight be the source of the river Alph (8)
>  **MONGOLIA** — where Kublai Khan his pleasure dome did decree
>
>  **N**ice work by Slartibartfast (6)
>  **NORWAY** — Slartibartfast designed the fjords. Go look it up in the HHGttG.
>
>  **O**nce a part of the Ottoman Empire (4)
>  **OMAN** — Ott(OMAN)
>
>  **P**iquant eclectic dishes served up in an old pan (6)
>  **POLAND** — (OLD PAN)*
>
>  **Q**uietly reading up a Desiderata quote (5)
>  **QATAR** — Deside(RATA Q<)oute
>
>  **R**esonating with someone in a hurry (6)
>  **RUSSIA** — sounds like "rusher".
>
>  **S**tarting in arid Asia, Abu set forth (11)
>  **SAUDI ARABIA** — (ARID ASIA ABU)*
>
>  **S**udden uplifting by an Indiana dust devil (5)
>  **SUDAN** — India(NA DUS<)t
>
>  **T**hanksgiving's reprieval (6)
>  **TURKEY** — stuffed and eaten on Thanksgiving day
>
>  **U**sually like Britain, with bad weather to the east (7)
>  **UKRAINE** — UK + RAIN + E (east)
>
>  **V**eiled activity can be found in Rome (11)
>  **VATICAN CITY** — (ACTIVITY CAN)*
>
>  **W**here the Earth answers a disputed situation (13)
>  **WESTERN SAHARA** — (EARTH ANSWERS A)*
>
>  **X**i likes a gin jinx cocktail kept separate (8)
>  **XINJIANG**, a region in western China — (A GIN JINX)*
>
>  **Y**ou see visual yoga after its break-up (10)
>  **YUGOSLAVIA** — (VISUAL YOGA)*
>
>  **Z**apped now I raze it to the ground (5)
>  **ZAIRE** — (I RAZE)*

The answers are all ...

> ... countries in Europe, Asia and Africa. Remember we are in 1991/92, so Yugoslavia still existed as country (but was at the brink of civil war) and the Democraric Republic of Congo was Zaire. The Soviet Union had just dissolved and Germany was reunited.
>
>  [image: map of listed countries]
>
>  The place of X is taken by the Xinjiang region in northwestern China. In the map, I've just paint-bucketed all of China, but Xinjiang has borders to Russia, Kyrgyzstan and Mongolia on VW's list.
>
>  The listed countries form a contiguous region with the exception of Vatican City, which would require Italy to be on the list, and Western Sahara, which would require several more countries on the list to connect to Chad.

VW claims that the trip ...

> started in **Vatican City** and ended in **Western Sahara**, but they could not have visited these in their VW without visting countries that are not on the A-Z list.

Comment: Very, very close, except that the last section doesn't comply with the narrative.

Comment: Oh, so that's the _third_ meaning of VW? Otherwise, I'm stumped.

Comment: Yes, **VW** went in the **VW** from **V** to **W**. Wanda says that they never did an A to Z journey, and that the impossible locations were the start and finish. They also form the central cross on the puzzle grid. Well done though. Unfortunately the only W and X places aren't strictly countries, which I tried to convey in their clue. I had to do the time shift to be able to make any suitable list of countries that would connect.

Comment: ... I wanted to make a grid that was actually a correct map too, so that words connected not just by letter but by land border, but I had to give up on that idea :)

Comment: That would have been the icing on the cake, but even so, the list of countries is an impressive construction.